# Working with Silverlight B2 and RC0

Tags: silverlight, upgrade, silverlight-2-rc0

I've been reading about the new developer-only RC0 for Silverlight, and the fact that it is supposed to be used only by developers to solve any breaking changes when upgrading from beta 2, so that when the actual S2 is released, migration is smoother.

My question is, since you are supposed to uninstall B2 tools and install RC0 in VS2008, is there any way to keep providing support and bugfixing for an existent B2 app, while maintaining a RC0 branch at the same time?

Or the only possible course of action is having a VM with VS2008 and B2 used for working with the B2 app until the RC is actually released?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A VM is really the only solution I've heard of so far for this. Hopefully we won't be in this limbo for too horribly long.

One thing you could do to make the VM a bit smaller is if you do your RC0 stuff on the VM, you can use Visual Web Developer Express 2008 SP1 on there instead of the full blown Visual Studio. Unfortunately you can't do the reverse and do the Beta 2 stuff on VWD Express.